# Java Date to Epoch, limited by Api 21 (Android) with Java7

Tags: java, date, kotlin, epoch

I've seen many useful responses on this, but using classes unavailable to me.

I have a correct Date object, and i've tryied different things, but when a review the result [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/) I can see, it's not working.

I can only use Java7  (or kotlin equivalent)

Here is my current incorrect code:

```
@JvmStatic fun getEpochNumberFromDate(date: Date):String{

        var calendar : Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.isLenient = false
        calendar.set(date.year, date.day,date.month,date.hours,date.minutes)

        Log.d("zzz","calendar date : "+calendar.timeInMillis.toString())

        Log.d("zzz","year: "+date.year+", month:"+date.month+",  date.time.toString():"+date.time.toString())


        return date.time.toString()
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem in a more specific way ?

Comment: "I have a correct Date object" - I suspect you don't actually. Currently you're using the system default time zone - is that deliberate? It's worth noting that `Date.getYear()` etc have been deprecated for *decades* and I'd strongly encourage you not to use them.

Comment: Could you provide an example input (Date) and output? The fact that the method is named getEpochNumberFromDate but returns a string is quite confusing. The fact that the 5 first lines of the method don't do anything useful is confusing too. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you have a (deprecated, old, etc.) `java.util.Date` object, is there something wrong with the `.getTime()` method?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow before posting. Your issue almost certainly addressed. And if it weren't, searching would have educated about the various issues so you could have more clearly stated a specific question with example code.

Comment: I believe that the code you have is correct. On Android API level 21 do consider ThreeTenABP instead of the poorly designed `Date` and `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it.  There is no need to use a Calendar at all.  Date.getTime() returns milliseconds since epoch.  You just need to divide by 1000.  If you're seeing other differences from that website, it's probably because of timezone issues.

Comment: Since an old-fashioned `Date` doesn’t have a time zone (and the epoch is time zone independent too), if you use `Date` correctly, there shouldn’t be any time zone issues.